# Dynamically assign click event

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, add-in

Is it possible to add a click event to a cell or range in an Excel worksheet from code in a C# add-in?

I am loading data from a web-service into a work sheet, but some of the columns (depending on local config) need to respond to user actions.

Is it possible from within the C# add-in code to dynamically assign click events to some columns, which would then call code in the add-in?

Comment: You can use Application Events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application_events(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: So only right-click and double-click?

Comment: You can also capture selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, no, not to a specific cell or range.

But you can add an event for the workbook and then check in your code whether the cell right-clicked should be treated differently.

So, in the main AddIn class, you can add:

```
private void MyAddin_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // setup event handlers
    Application.SheetBeforeRightClick +=
        MyRightClickFunction; 
}

private void MyRightClickFunction(object sh, Excel.Range target, ref bool cancel)
{
    // 'target' is the cell or selected range clicked
    ... 
}
```